# SQL adding carriage returns to text

Tags: sql, database, carriage-return

I'm quite a beginner at SQL and have a table with a column in which I have text, I want to use this text as the body of an email.

I want this body text to have carriage returns in it, but each time I send an email using it, it just comes out as one line. The text is this:

> Please find your latest statement of account. Could you review any due
>   or pending invoices & confirm payment by this Friday.   If you have
>   any queries please contact xx.xx@xx.Com
>
> Regards   xx

How do I make it so that carriage returns are kept in the text, and used when adding the text to an email?

Comment: Are you sending the mail as HTML or plain text? If they are stored in the database and the message is plain text, the line breaks will be honored. But if it's HTML you'll need to convert them to `<br />`

Comment: There is no carriage return in your sample text either...

Comment: It's being sent as plain text message, how do i store the line breaks in the database tho? I have changed the example message to have the formatting i wish the email to have.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CHAR(13) function to insert new lines.  For example:

```
PRINT 'Hello ' + CHAR(13) + 'Safi'
```

Or

```
PRINT 'Hello ' + CHAR(10) + 'Safi'
```

A better exmaple:

```
PRINT 'Please find your latest statement of account. Could you review any due or pending invoices & confirm payment by this Friday.' + CHAR(10) + 'If you have any queries please contact xx.xx@xx.Com' + CHAR(10) + 'Regards'
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the reply. you state CHAR(13) at the top of your answer but then have CHAR(10) in the examples which is a bit confusing.  Also, the PRINT thing confuses me, true if i copy that into Management studio and execute it prints it out with the line breaks. If, however, I replace the PRINT with an INSERT and insert the text into the table and run the process to place it into the email the line breaks do not appear still, with either CHAR(10) or CHAR(13) used

Comment: When you output the text into the email i assume you create a string. Use either CHAR(10) or CHAR(13) to break up the string and create new lines. If you have an example of your code, that might be helpful.

Comment: `+` is not the string concatention operator in *SQL* (it might be in some non-standard DBMS dialects though)